# Does a question need to include source code to be on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

There is a comment on [this question](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/810/is-making-a-living-by-working-only-on-floss-projects-a-viable-option) suggesting that the question should be closed. I was very surprised by the reason given:

> I'm fairly certain that since this does not involve any sample of code, but a situation in which you are discussing a job about situations wherein you code, that this is indeed off-topic. I agree that the workplace board is a better place to get an answer to a question like this.

Please answer with your opinions on this so we can see a clear community consensus on whether source code is required to make a question on topic.

Answer (score 9):

As per the site scope, Open Source is not just code, and people shouldn't have to simply "show" the code to make sure that their question won't be criticized as off-topic. This is similar to what happened when discussing the sites [reference policy](https://opensource.meta.stackexchange.com/a/86/69). Not only that, but the reason demonstrate a lack of understanding for what Open Source is. It doesn't just apply to software, but to everything.

Including source code doesn't mean anything for these questions, we're a site about the organization and development of open projects.